# WCF endpoint address without .svc extension

Tags: wcf, configuration, iis-7.5

I have WCF service up and running but today I thought what if I remove .svc extension from realative address and access my service in this way? net.tcp://serveraddress/services/service I but as soon as I changed config files program did not start. this programs and service are developed using .NET 4.0 and WCF 4 ad service itself is hosted in IIS 7.5

it is possible to access services in this way while having them hosted in IIS?

Comment: Have you tried changing the default page for the application in IIS to point to the svc file, or are you trying to avoid that all together?

Comment: I did not try changing default page but i prefer to avoid that as default page is not good solution because that every service needs to have same file name and this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with a handler in IIS. I also use extensionless WCF services, and I modified my web.config file to make it work. Add this to your web.config to see if it will help:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>

<handlers> 
<remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
<add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add 
        name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
        preCondition="integratedMode" 
        verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" 
        type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,  
          Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/> 
    </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: '<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SmapleServiceRule" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^virtualpath>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="servicename.svc" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>'
is that right way tu rewrite? why shoud i remove and add handlers?

Comment: I still ca not achieve desired result can someone explain how to configure that?

Comment: does anyone know to to do this? my problem here is that I am using net.tcp binding. if a refer to it in http request fro browser it works but not for net.tcp

Answer (score 1):

I have hosted my WCF service without svc file. I am adding ServiceRoute to RouteTable in Application_Start method in Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("AdminDataService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(AdminService)));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("AuthenticationService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(AuthenticationService)));
}
```